# Get screen size of Storyboard preview programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

In order to get device screen size in Swift, I use this code:

`UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size`

It works great, except when I'm using Storyboard previews. In my `@IBDesignable` `UILabel` subclass, I use a smaller font if the user is on an iPhone4 and a bigger font otherwise. This works just fine using the simulator, but it doesn't work for my Storyboard previews.

All the previews—from iPhone4 to iPad Pro—load the smaller font, meaning they are returning 320x480 for my code above. Here's my question: what code will return the device screen size of the Storyboard previews (e.g., that I could plug into `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`)?

Comment: I'd still be interested in an answer to this question, but in the meantime I ended up creating a subclass of UILabel that shrinks in height when the frame height becomes smaller than the intrinsic content height. This way, what I see on the Storyboard preview has been the same as on the device. (And it also let me remove all "device checks" from the code. :)